# Undefined function even with correctly dependancies specified in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I seem to be getting this more on my local machine as apposed to the staging. Its not recognizing a couple of functions that make a reference to certain libraries / modules so my guess is that its loading my custom initilisation scripts before the said library  / modules.

But my scripts have been correctly specified for dependancies as far as i can see so I not sure how to rectify this.

```
function scripts() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-init', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js',array(),'',true);
wp_enqueue_script('velocity-init', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.velocity.min.js', array('jquery-init'),'',true);
wp_enqueue_script('colorbox-init', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.colorbox-min.js',array('jquery-init'),'',true);
wp_enqueue_script('isotope-init', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js',array('jquery-init'),'',true);
wp_enqueue_script('slick-init', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/slick.min.js',array('jquery-init'),'',true);
wp_enqueue_script('fitvids-init', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/fitvids.js',array('jquery-init'),'',true);
wp_enqueue_script('scrolltop-init', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.scrollTop.js',array('jquery-init'),'',true);
wp_enqueue_script('scripts-init', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/scripts.js',array( 'scrolltop-init','isotope-init', 'fitvids-init', 'slick-init', 'colorbox-init', 'velocity-init'),'',true);
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scripts' );
```

The last file is 333 line long and loads all code in a function like so:

```
(function ($) { } )(jQuery);
```

Is there something I'm not doing correctly in my javascript script.js file? All code runs fine and are a series of intilaisations, conditionals, html appends, animation menus, styling, etc, no functions.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery noConflict Wrappers

The jQuery library included with WordPress is set to the noConflict() mode (see wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js). This is to prevent compatibility problems with other JavaScript libraries that WordPress can link.

In the noConflict() mode, the global $ shortcut for jQuery is not available, so you can still use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(#somefunction) ...
});
```

but the following will either throw an error, or use the $ shortcut as assigned by other library.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(#somefunction) ...
});
```

However, if you really like the short $ instead of jQuery, you can use the following wrapper around your code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Inside of this function, $() will work as an alias for jQuery()
    // and other libraries also using $ will not be accessible under this shortcut
});
```

That wrapper will cause your code to be executed when the DOM is fully constructed. If, for some reason, you want your code to execute immediately instead of waiting for the DOM ready event, then you can use this wrapper method instead:

```
(function($) {
    // Inside of this function, $() will work as an alias for jQuery()
    // and other libraries also using $ will not be accessible under this shortcut
})(jQuery);
```

Alternatively, you can always reasign jQuery to another shortcut of your choice and leave the $ shorcut to other libraries:

```
var $j = jQuery;
```

[Documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

Comment: I know this already, but thanks for your thorough answer and effort